# Orderby weighted average in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to sort a table by a weighted average of two columns. The weights for the columns are stored in a controller's scope. When I try to refer to these weights in my orderBy expression sorting is not done correctly.

```
 <tr ng-repeat = "x in fruitdata | orderBy:'cost.apples*apples + cost.oranges * oranges'">
```

Fiddle of what I want: https://jsfiddle.net/t3op50p9/2/

If I hard code weights instead everything works as it should

```
 <tr ng-repeat = "x in fruitdata | orderBy:'1.89*apples + 1.49 * oranges'">
```

Fiddle with hard coded weights (not what I want): https://jsfiddle.net/t3op50p9/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function in your scope to be used to calculate the weight for ordering

```
$scope.orderFn = function (fruit) {
    return fruit.apples * $scope.cost.apples + fruit.oranges * $scope.cost.oranges;
}
```

`ng-repeat="x in fruitdata | orderBy: orderFn:true"` (note: the `true` on the end reverses the order generated by the ordering function making the largest weight on top.)

https://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/t3op50p9/6/

Comment: looks cool with custom filter..but mine modification in OP question does make sense?

Comment: Yeah, it's nice to have it in the template, but you lose the ability to do simple unit tests against this functionality.

Comment: +1, but I'd suggest giving the function a more descriptive name, like `getCost`, or something. That way it has the added benefit of being nicely called in the table cell as well, DRYing up the code.

Comment: Both this awnser and @pankajparkar work. Thanks. The advantage of this function is that it can be included in the table cell, and i have a few computer columns so it helps keep it clean

Comment: @DRobinson Yes, +1 your comment. "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things." --Phil Karlton

Answer (score 1):

You should use `cost.apples` & `cost.oranges` shouldn't be inside the `'` single quotes as they are not the part of `ng-repeat` repeat array, so they will binded as string concatenation.

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in fruitdata | orderBy:cost.apples+'*apples + '+ cost.oranges+' * oranges'">
    <td> {{x.oranges}} </td>
    <td> {{x.apples}} </td>
    <td> {{x.apples * cost.apples + x.oranges * cost.oranges}} </td>
</tr>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t3op50p9/7/)